# Changing Php's Handler Name

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-php

On my apache server I'd like to run multiple versions of PHP concurrently so that I can easily switch between them depending on the needs of the project. I noticed that some shared hosting providers who offer multiple versions of PHP require you to define the version of PHP you need in your `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

I'd like to implement something like this on my server so that I can easily switch PHP versions:

```
AddHandler application/xhttpd-php53 .php
 # .. or ..
AddHandler application/xhttpd-php54 .php
 # .. or ..
AddHandler application/xhttpd-php55 .php
```

However all of the versions of PHP that I've compiled have a handler named `application/xhttpd-php` or `php5-script`. I've tried to search for a `./configure` flag that allows you to change these handler names, but nothing turned up.

I searched the [PHP github repo](https://github.com/php/php-src) for these [two](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=application/x-httpd-php&source=c) [strings](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=php5-script&ref=cmdform) and this is what I found:

- `/sapi/apache2filter/sapi_apache2.c` ([Lines 666-668](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/apache2filter/sapi_apache2.c#L666-L668))
- `/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c` ([Lines 68-70](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L68-L70))
- `/main/php.h` ([Line 242](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php.h#L242))
- `/sapi/apache/mod_php5.c` ([Line 979](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/apache/mod_php5.c#L979))
- `/sapi/apache_hooks/mod_php5.c` ([Line 1408](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/apache_hooks/mod_php5.c#L1408))

Would it be safe to replace these strings with the new handler name and version number, or is there a wider used (ora actually documented) way to change the handler name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the php version as a module and another versions as cgi. If you would need to use specific php version in some specific project (vhost) you can use something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
    DocumentRoot /vhosts/php55.example.net/
    ServerName php55.example.net

    ScriptAlias /php-fastcgi/ /usr/local/php-5.5.1/bin/

    AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    Action php-fastcgi /php-fastcgi/php-cgi

    <Directory /vhosts/php55.example.net>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
    DocumentRoot /vhosts/php54.example.net/
    ServerName php54.example.net

    ScriptAlias /php-fastcgi/ /usr/local/php-5.4.17/bin/

    AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    Action php-fastcgi /php-fastcgi/php-cgi

    <Directory /vhosts/php54.example.net>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Solid advice. It's what I ended up using in the end. I tried my hack-y  workaround from the question and Apache segfaulted after I added more than one PHP module. Seems that FPM is the way to go! Thanks!